# ReactJs for some sort of complex calculator?

Tags: reactjs

I've done some special calculators for our customers. These are web apps with multiple input fields (> 40 - 80 individual fields). The user types in some values (mainly currency numbers and percentages) and the calculator gives various outputs from the calculation. Last one was calculating the insolvency rate (used by lawyers).

These apps are build with jQuery and JavaScript.

No a new app of this sort lurks on the horizon.

Because I want and have to learn ReactJs in the next months, I wonder if React would be the right choice for this kind of project. Plus, I need more maintainable code.

What would you use as a framework for that?

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: If React is thought to be risky, could you just make your jQuery code more maintainable? I don't think it is inherently unmaintainable, and you'll be working with a technology you know.

Comment: Oh, yes, I could. But a) I have time since it's not an urgent project and b) I have to learn React anyways. So I thought it would be nice to learn React while creating a real life app. My question is more like: would this be a real use case for React or would a developer fluent in React say "please don't do it React because of...".